# Dots in email address of 'Gmail for work' service: are they ignored?

Tags: google-apps-email

According to this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919325/should-i-remove-all-dots-before-the-sign-in-emails, 'dot' is a valid character in an email address.

But for Google's gmail service, they say they do not recognise 'dot'. Quoted from https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10313?hl=en

> Gmail doesn't recognize dots as characters within usernames, you can add or remove the dots from a Gmail address without changing the actual destination address; they'll all go to your inbox, and only yours.

I am using 'Gmail for Work' at the moment. Let say my work domain is '@awesome.com'. To my surprise, 'j.e.n@awesome.com' caused a bounce from google. I am expecting the email will be delivered to 'jen@awesome.com'

Does 'Gmail for work' handle email address differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail for work/Google Apps accounts do count dots as part of the email address so the two address are unique.  From [this help article](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10313?hl=en):

> One last thing: Google Apps does recognize dots. If you'd like to have a dot in your username, please ask your domain administrator to add your preferred username as a nickname.